# How to write code for global.ascx.cs in dotnetnuke website?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, query-string, dotnetnuke, global-asax

I need to write some code in application level variable in global.ascx.cs file in my dotnetnuke website to change the url of some pages with querystring management.

I got a [tutorial from youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zlgo6M637Kc) to do that by editing global.ascx.cs

Comment: facing same problem.....

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you are trying to do, so that I can try to assist you. Adding code to global.ascx.cs in DNN is VERY uncommon and there are most likely better ways to do the same thing, but I need to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah like Chris said it is highly uncommon, but without more detail to your goal we won't be able to assist you.

Comment: Chris & Greg @

I am trying to change Url of some page @ runtime.

My page url is 
http://localhost:8656/indiesblog/BlogPost.aspx?Title=Download%20torrent%20using%20IDM&ID=5

I want to change it to...
http://localhost:8656/indiesblog/BlogPost/Download-torrent-using-IDM.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifications to URLs within DotNetNuke typically happen through an HTTPmodule, you can register your own, or you can use a tool such as URLMaster for customizing URLs within DNN.

Another option is to make changes to the SITEURLS.CONFIG file in the root of a DNN site. You can find an interface to edit siteurls.config in the host/host settings page, under the friendly URL settings.

Comment: Chris. I have a url i just want to make it look different everytime.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It helps point the user in a different direction, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: According to several DNN support posts this is the appropriate answer. Their global.asax inherits from DotNetNukeHttpApplication, not HttpApplication, so you truly cannot do it.  Other than doing some partial class on that or editing the actual source and recompiling, the HttpModule is more than likely the way to go.  
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/428293/scope/posts/globalasaxcs

Actually this other article is not DNN specific and also points to HttpModules as an alternative to Global.asax.  http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2006/06/12/global-asax-use-httpmodules-instead/